# Angular : add parameter before hash without refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hash, routes

i am creating a angular app and want to add few parameter before the hash in url dynamically without refreshing the page or controller.

eg: suppose initial url is

```
http://localhost:3000/#/xyz
```

i want to add parameter before the hash

```
http://localhost:3000/?sort=desc#/xyz
```

Note:

- I can't implement pretty url concept of angular because i am not allowed to do any configuration at server side.
- I tried HTML5 history but getting error like infinite digest cycle or controller reloads again and again

Comment: You'd have to rewrite the routing in angular completely. Out of interest why can't you have your url to be `http://localhost:3000/#/xyz?sort=desc`

Comment: I don't want # in href of a link(some problem in click tracking).... i might have link which points to url somthing like "http://localhost:3000/?event=holi" when user clicks on it , angular routing will add "#/xyz" ...